# JQGrid popup shows only once

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning MVC in which I'm told to use jqgrid. Everything else works properly but Add popup shows only once i.e. when page loads it shows on first click but doesn't on second click. I could not find the reason. Here is my code. Can anybody help?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Add-Documents").click(function () {
    $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {
        url: '/SuperAdmin/AddDocuments',
        addCaption: "Add Document",
        bSubmit: "Submit",
        bCancel: "Cancel",
        bClose: "Close",
        saveData: "Data has been changed! Save changes?",
        bYes: "Yes",
        bNo: "No",
        bExit: "Cancel",
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        afterComplete: function () {
            $("#tblJQGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    });        
});
```

})

Comment: Can you clarify it. Where is  the add popup?

Comment: It's the method for showing the popup according to JQGrid documentation

Comment: It is still too general is it the add popup can you point me there in your code?

Comment: @AmeteBlessed It's the code which generates popup. I was able to find the solution to it. It was not creating new instance of dialog so I had to add one extra parameter for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by doing some R&D for it. I had to add one extra parameter recreateForm because it was not recreating new instance on click. new code looks like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("#Add-Documents").click(function () {
    $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {
        url: '/SuperAdmin/AddDocuments',
        addCaption: "Add Document",
        bSubmit: "Submit",
        bCancel: "Cancel",
        bClose: "Close",
        saveData: "Data has been changed! Save changes?",
        bYes: "Yes",
        bNo: "No",
recreateForm: true,
        bExit: "Cancel",
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        afterComplete: function () {
            $("#tblJQGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    });        
});
```